# script GNU to install kaggle API

Tags: bash, scripting, kaggle

This is my first time trying to download a dataset ('train.csv') from the API.
I am currently trying to install in ubuntu the API with the instruction `sudo pip install kaggle-cli` but it's not being possible.
Error: `pip: order not found`

Is there any other option?
I want to work then with GNU (awk, bash,....)

The [information](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api) I found is not being enough to solve the problem.

Could someone let me know how to install it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "but it's not being possible"? Which error message did you get?

Comment: @PierreFrançois, I mean I type the mentioned code and I got the message (on terminal):  pip: order not found

Comment: Pleas put diagnostics messages into your question, not in a comment. Also, questions for installing software are better asked at [su].

Comment: @user1934428 I didn't know about Super User. I'll post it right now. Regarding the error into the question, done.

Comment: Also, you need tag your question with _python_. The error itself is unrelated to bash, so I would remove this tag.

Comment: @user1934428, but I want to do it with scripting, not in Python. And this is mentioned in the question

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, the error message comes from the `pip` command, not from your script. Don't tell me that you want to install the package without using pip?